# Limits on number of values in "IN" queries

Tags: sql, mysql

Given a query like the following:

```
DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID in (1,2,3,4,....);
```

- Is there an upper limit to the number of values in the inclusion? (I've seen Oracle complain at 1000, but that was a long time ago. I have no idea if that was installation-dependant, oracle-version dependant, etc. etc., or how mysql limits this.
- What are the performance implications? Would it be faster to break up the set of values into smaller subsets and send multiple delete requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

> The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) value.

As to performance, I would break up the queries when they start approaching a thousand IDs or so.  `IN` is pretty well-optimized, but it still doesn't seem like any good can come of throwing enormous lists at it.

Comment: Thank you for posting from the doc - I don't know why people don't do this immediately for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure that your statement will always work, put them in a temp table and do the IN statement against it.

Comment: How exactly would that be done?  
"DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID in bar.id;"?

Comment: DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM BAR)

Comment: Your solution is useful in that there are other ways to accomplish this; however I'm actually looking for information on big, honking "IN" clauses, and whether or not they'll make the db explode.Additionally, given that you'll have to do an insert and then a join, how will that impact the performance? 
If I were checking against a much larger number of id's this might be a good solution, though.

Comment: @Steve - I understand. It just gives me the creeps.